# Difference between UITextAlignmentCenter and NSTextAlignmentCenter

Tags: ios6, text-alignment

What is difference between `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` ?

For example when I used this code:

```
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Xcode said:

> UITextAlignmentCenter is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0

But when I use `NSTextAlignmentCenter`, it was fine - so what can be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause s that `UITextAlignment` is deprecated in iOS 6 and the actual `textAlignment` property's type is `NSTextAlignment`.
See: [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/textAlignment)

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
# define ALIGN_CENTER NSTextAlignmentCenter
#else
# define ALIGN_CENTER UITextAlignmentCenter
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's Solution with example :

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
# define ALIGN_CENTER NSTextAlignmentCenter
#else
# define ALIGN_CENTER UITextAlignmentCenter
#endif

UILabel* your_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
label.text = @"CENTER TEXT";
label.textAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
[self addSubview:your_label];
```

Answer (score 0):

The raison is :

- UITextAlignmentCenter is only for IOS
- NSTextAlignmentCenter is for IOS and MacOSX

Apple want help/push IOS developper to develop for MacOSX too.